# Compile error with `let` in Swift switch statements

Tags: swift

In Swift, you can get a slice of an array using a range operator, like this:

```
let list: String[] = ["first", "middle", "last"]
let cdr = list[1..list.endIndex]
assert(cdr == ["middle", "last"])
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in a recursive function that takes a `String[]` parameter, but not having any luck:

```
func last(xs: String[]) -> String? {
    switch xs {
    case let (singleItemList) where singleItemList.endIndex == 1:
        return singleItemList[0]
    case let(multiItemList) where multiItemList.endIndex > 1:
        let cdr: String[] = multiItemList[1..multiItemList.endIndex] // compilation error!
        return last(cdr)
    default:
        return nil // empty list
    }
}


last(["first", "middle", "last"])
last(["last"])
last([])
```

The middle case statement doesn't compile.  It fails with this error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:14:29: error: could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
        let cdr: String[] = multiItemList[1..multiItemList.endIndex] // compilation error!
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Am I doing something wrong?   Is the type of the value I get from `let` somehow not a `String[]`?

I'm trying to come up with an equivalent recursive `last` method to this one from Scala (yes, I understand that there are easier ways to get the last element built-in to Swift and Scala):

```
def last[T](xs: List[T]): T = xs match {
    case List() => throw new Error("last of empty list")
    case List(x) => x
    case y :: ys => last(ys)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`multiItemList[1..multiItemList.endIndex]` is not an array. You have to convert it to an array first. Change the line into the following:

```
let cdr: String[] = Array(multiItemList[1..multiItemList.endIndex])
```

Comment: The actual type is `String[].SliceType` aka `Slice<String>`.