# How can I tell what the class of an instance variable is in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there any easy way to tell what `class` an instance variable is in a Swift?  In the JVM-based languages that I'm used to, you can do something like `println(value.class)` to get it's class.

Is there something equivalent in Swift?

The closest thing I can find in the docs is the ability to do "type checking" with the [`is <Class>` keyword](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html) but that only helps me guess a little bit.

I've run into a [few situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100707/compile-error-with-let-in-swift-switch-statements) in playing around where I thought I had one type of class, but actually had another and didn't know how to know for sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the class of a variable in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097825/how-to-get-the-class-of-a-variable-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks David, I hadn't seen that one in my searching.  It's a similar question, but not exactly the same.  That's asking how to test if a class is a particular type (using `is`, which I noted above).  I don't want to test, I want to print out the class name so I can see what it is.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `type.self` to return a type that can be passed into a method that accepts a type-level argument. For example, `UILabel.self` can be passed to the `isKindOfClass` method call. The string representation of the class can be found via `dynamicType.description()`:

```
var label = UILabel()
println(label.dynamicType.description())
println(label.isKindOfClass(UILabel.self))
```

**Swift-3**

```
var label = UILabel()
println(type(of: label).description())
```

> **Output**
>  UILabel
>  true

Here's a bit more background -- there are two expressions to be aware of: the postfix self expression and the dynamic type expression. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html):

> **Postfix Self**
>    A postfix self expression consists of an expression or the name of a
>   type, immediately followed by .self. It has the following forms:
>
> ```
> expression.self
> type.self
> ```
>
> The first form evaluates to the value of the expression. For example,
>   x.self evaluates to x.
>
> *The second form evaluates to the value of the type*. Use this form to
>   access a type as a value. For example, because SomeClass.self
>   evaluates to the SomeClass type itself, you can pass it to a function
>   or method that accepts a type-level argument
>
> **Dyamic Type Expression**
>  
>   A dynamicType expression consists of an expression, immediately
>   followed by .dynamicType. It has the following form:
>
> ```
> expression.dynamicType
> ```
>
> The expression can’t be the name of a type. The entire dynamicType
>   expression evaluates to the value of the runtime type of the
>   expression.

Comment: I'm not seeing a `description()` on the test case that I've got `let list:String[] = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
let cdr = list[1..2];
println(cdr.dynamicType.description());` but the error that I'm getting (`error: 'Slice<String>.Type' does not have a member named 'description'`) gives me the info that I need so I'm marking this correct, thanks!

Comment: @TedNaleid Yep. Some classes have a description function set on them, some do not. It's still early days for the language and I expect there will be much better reflection support in the future.

Comment: @TedNaleid: `description()` is declared as a class method of `NSObject`, which means you can only use `.dynamicType.description()` on expressions with compile-time type that is a subclass of `NSObject`. `cdr` has type `Slice<String>`, which is not even a class, let alone subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: @newacct It's not only `NSObject` subclasses that can have a `description` property. Any object which conforms to the `printable` protocol will have it.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons: You are confusing two different things. Objects that conform to `Printable` have a `description` *property*, i.e. you would access it as `.description`. That is not what's happening here. Here you're calling the *method* `.description()`. This method is a *class method*, so it is called on types (not objects) representing NSObject subclasses. *Types* do not conform to `Printable`. The two are not compatible because if you try to access a method as a property, you get a function.

Answer (score 6):

As of beta 6 `_stdlib_getTypeName` gets the mangled type name of a variable. Paste this into an empty playground:

```
import Foundation

class PureSwiftClass {
}

var myvar0 = NSString() // Objective-C class
var myvar1 = PureSwiftClass()
var myvar2 = 42
var myvar3 = "Hans"

println( "TypeName0 = \(_stdlib_getTypeName(myvar0))")
println( "TypeName1 = \(_stdlib_getTypeName(myvar1))")
println( "TypeName2 = \(_stdlib_getTypeName(myvar2))")
println( "TypeName3 = \(_stdlib_getTypeName(myvar3))")
```

The output is:

```
TypeName0 = NSString
TypeName1 = _TtC13__lldb_expr_014PureSwiftClass
TypeName2 = _TtSi
TypeName3 = _TtSS
```

[Ewan Swick's blog entry](http://www.eswick.com/2014/06/inside-swift/) helps to decipher these strings:

e.g. `_TtSi` stands for Swift's internal `Int` type.

[Mike Ash has a great blog entry covering the same topic](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html).

Comment: I got an error: `use of unsolved identifier _stdlib_getTypeName`